# how to use composed_of in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, simple-form

I'm development an application using Rails 3.1.1 + devise 1.5.0 + simple_form 1.5.2. I need that an user has an address and then I created one class address. The address class is used as a composed_of in user. The problem is that when I post form with data I receive this error message "WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: address". How do I solve this?

My source code is here: [source](https://gist.github.com/1881421)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `User` model.

```
attr_accessible :address_attributes
```

For more information, refer here - [attr-accessible-in-rails-active-record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789996/attr-accessible-in-rails-active-record)

Comment: I tried add attr_acessible :address_attributes where attributes is the attributes of address, but no works and then I tried attr_accessible :address and nothing. When I specific :address in attr_accessible explodes this exception "NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create undefined method `postal_code' for #<ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess:0x007f9a70c954c0>"

Comment: Changed after to https://gist.github.com/1881421 and then I receive this error message "NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create
undefined method `valid?' for #<Address:0x007ffdb459dc38>". What's the problem?