# Creating records in rails console

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am new with ruby on rails and I am following Ruby on Rails 3 Essential Training 2010 from Lynda.

I have a problem with creating records in rails console even though I create the subject it returns nil. This is the code from the console:

> vane@vane-HP-G70-Notebook-PC:~/Sites/simple_cms$ rails c
>
> Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.8)
>
> 1.9.3-p194 :001 > subject = Subject.new(:name => "Fourth Subject", :position => 4, :visible => true)
>
> => Subject id: nil, name: nil, position: nil, visible: false, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>
> 1.9.3-p194 :002 > subject.save
>      (0.1ms)  BEGIN
>     SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `subjects` (`created_at`, `name`, `position`, `updated_at`, `visible`) VALUES ('2012-10-10 15:06:11', NULL, NULL, '2012-10-10 15:06:11', 0)
>      (56.4ms)  COMMIT
>
> => true

It doesn't show any error so I don't now what to do. Any help will be appreciated.

This is what i have in app>models subject.rb:

```
    class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base 
    attr_accessor :name, :position, :visible 
    attr_accessible :name, :position, :visible
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to make your attributes [accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789996/attr-accessible-in-rails-active-record) so they can be assigned in your `new` call.

Answer (score 0):

After i removed this line

> attr_accessor :name, :position, :visible

from subject.rb the problem got solved.