# Active Model MassAssignmentSecurity Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, omniauth

I'm Getting an Error: I'm developing a web with Facebook Integration.. I'm new in ruby on rails. can you help with my problem.

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in SessionsController#create

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: name
```

**This is my controller:**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    #render :json => request.env['omniauth.auth'].to_yaml
   auth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
    unless @auth = Authorization.find_from_hash(auth)
      @auth = Authorization.create_from_hash(auth, current_user)
    end

    self.current_user = @auth.user  
    render :text => "Welcome, #{current_user.name}."
   end
end
```

**This is my user model:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authorizations
  attr_accessor :name, :uid, :provider

  def self.create_from_hash!(hash)
    #create(:name => hash['user_info']['name'])
   create(:name => hash.info.name)
  end
end
```

**This is my authorization model:**

```
class Authorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :user_id, :uid, :provider
  validates_uniqueness_of :uid, :scope => :provider

  def self.find_from_hash(hash)
    find_by_provider_and_uid(hash['provider'], hash['uid'])
  end

  def self.create_from_hash(hash, user = nil)
    user ||= User.create_from_hash!(hash)
    Authorization.create(:user => user, :uid => hash['uid'], :provider => hash['provider'])
  end
end
```

how can I fix this .. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You certainly have enabled [mass assignment protection](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment) (with `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true` in your config file), so you need to explicitly indicate which attributes can be updated by methods like `update_attributes`. You do it with `attr_accessible`.

In the `User` model, replace the following line (that seems useless)

```
attr_accessor :name, :uid, :provider
```

by

```
attr_accessible :name, :uid, :provider
```

See questions related to `attr_accessor` and `attr_accessible` for further informations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793098/usage-of-attr-accessor-in-rails), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789996/attr-accessible-in-rails-active-record) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136420/difference-between-attr-accessor-and-attr-accessible)

Comment: Actually I made it last night but thanks for your reply :).. That's exactly what I do to fix my problem :D

Comment: Man, I had sidekiq running and it was using update_attributes and this was throwing all kinds of errors because of that