# ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error with Rails 4 without a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following method in my User model.

```
def self.create_from(house:)
  create!(
    house: house,
    uuid: generate_uuid,
  )
end
```

Why am I getting a `ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error` for both `house` and `uuid` if I am not calling `create_from` from a controller? What is the suggested way to solve this in Rails 4.2? I am used to use `strong_params` when calling from a Controller, but this model method is called not from a controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly have enabled mass assignment protection (with `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true` in your config file), so you need to explicitly indicate which attributes can be updated by methods like update_attributes. You do it with `attr_accessible`.

In the models, use `attr_accessible`

See questions related to `attr_accessor` and `attr_accessible` for further informations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793098/usage-of-attr-accessor-in-rails), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789996/attr-accessible-in-rails-active-record) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136420/difference-between-attr-accessor-and-attr-accessible)

Credit:
[Active Model MassAssignmentSecurity Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008751/active-model-massassignmentsecurity-error)